# BitTorrent sync file permissions (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, sync, bittorrent

I started using BitTorrent sync last night, as a do-it-yourself Dropbox project, and it works amazing, except for one thing...

On my Ubuntu 13.10 laptop, all the file permissions are messed up, and are under root by default.

I either need to know how to:

- Change the default permissions to allow me to make changes
- Change the BitTorrent sync user to mine, allowing it, odviously, to fall under me...

-OR-

- Something else you guys can think of.

Comment: You should run `btsync` under the correct user. Like `sudo -u username /path/to/btsync`. Also see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/722431/bittorrent-sync-username).